# Remote access to cassandra Azure windows Instance

Tags: java, azure, cassandra

I have installed Cassandra on Microsoft azure instance from http://www.planetcassandra.org/cassandra/ and trying to access remotely from java client.I have enabled endpoints for port no 9042 but could not access it remotely.  After googling I have modified `listen_address` to local IP of azure instance ,`rpc_address` to public IP and `broadcast_rpc_address` to 255.255.255.255 in cassandra.yaml file but still I could not access the instance form my java client.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to refer to the article [Running Cassandra with Linux on Azure and Accessing it from Node.js](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-cassandra-nodejs) to set your Cassandra using PowerShell. It's for Linux instance, but I think it's helpful for you. And the comment  at the bottom of the article, a blog shows more details as reference.

Meanwhile, the simple way to install cassandra is create a `Datastax Enterprise` instance from Azure Marketplace, please see https://ms.portal.azure.com/?feature.relex=*%2CHubsExtension#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Marketplace/GalleryFeaturedMenuItemBlade/selectedMenuItemId/home/searchQuery/cassandra. Then, you don't need to consider for installing on Azure, please see the [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/community/events/getting-started-with-datastax-enterprise-8-mar-we/) for getting started with Datastax Enterprise.

Hope it helps.